# Rudin's proof of lemma 7.25

Tags: measure-theory

In his book "Real and Complex Analysis",he proved Lemma 7.25.
He said *"Since $m(F)=0$, $F$ can be covered by balls $B_i=B(x_i,r_i)$, where $x_i∈F$, $r_i<1/p$, in such a way that $\sum m(B_i)<\epsilon$."*

I can't understand what he said.
Please tell me how to construct such a cover.

Comment: follows from the definition of the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Namely $m(F)=\inf\{m(U): U\text{open and} F\subset U\}$. Since $m(F)=0$, $m(F)<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$. The result follows from this.

Answer (score 0):

Lebesgue Measure of a set is defined to be

$m(F)=\inf\{\sum |B(x_i,r_i)|:F\subset \cup_i B(x_i,r_i)\}$.

If $m(F)=0$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a collection of balls whose union contains $F$ and the sum of whose measure is below $\epsilon$.

Therefore, what Rudin says follows from the definition of measure and infimum.

Comment: Strictly speaking, one has to work a bit to achieve that the centers can be chosen to lie in $F$ and to get $r_i <1/p$, but apart from that you are right.